# How to check the given point is in selected line or not

Tags: vba, line, point, autocad

I am having a line,now i am randomly given a point.
   I want to check whether the given point is on the line or not?

I am using autocad with vba

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do this by creating a point entity and use the method IntersectWith with the line.